# WINUI3 Uno Platform Microsoft Store runFullTrust warning

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3, uno-platform

I have been in the process of migrating one of my project from a standard UWP project to an Uno platform based project to allow me a wider variety of devices to publish to. After overcoming a number of hurdles I generate my msixbundle and submit this to the Microsoft store. Because the original application was published with a .appxupload it need too be some kind of bundle to accept it. When i submit the bundle i receive the following warning

> Package acceptance validation warning: The following restricted
> capabilities require approval before you can use them in your app:
> runFullTrust.

In my package manifest the only capability ticked is Internet (Client). Nothing else is ticked and the application doesn't need anything to work.

Any idea where this has come from or is set and how I might go about changing this to the correct value. I have done quite a bit of googling and some places suggest ticking or unticking certain things on the package submission page(nothing i ticked on unticked seemed to help) or is this simply because it is uno platform?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

As a test I created a brand new uno platform application I also created a new app in the Microsoft app store linked the two. Left every single capability unticked(that's right none were checked) produced and msix submitted it to the store and i am receiving the exact same error. This leads me to think this is because it is an UNO platform app.

In case it is useful im using vs 2022 17.3.6.

Answer (score 1):

This being a store submission question, you may want to check out UWP community server; plenty of people there with apps in the store, someone must have hit the same roadblock as you. https://uwpcommunity.com/